# Where to put controllers in an Express.js project

Tags: javascript, express

I'm still pretty new to software development and one thing I am having difficulty understanding is the directory architecture of different types of projects. I am about to start building an Express project, and I like to separate out controller classes rather than putting logic inside route callbacks. But I don't really know where I should put my controllers. Here is my project structure right now:

```
.
├── bin
├── config
├── controllers
├── migrations
├── models
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   └── stylesheets
├── routes
├── seeders
└── views
```

This was generated by the Sequelize CLI, but I added `controllers` to the root directory. Should I put controllers in a `src` directory? If anyone could help me understand how to set this up in the most efficient way I'd be grateful. There seems to be so many opinions out there and conflicting information. Thanks.

Comment: This structure looks like a library that does not group the books by their genre but by the color of the cover. It is easier to work on a project that keeps the files that belong to the same functionality (business-wise) in the same directory. It is also easier for new members of the team to get used with the structure and find their way into it.

Comment: @axiac Okay, but that's not very helpful. The structure was generated by the express-generator and the sequelize CLI. If there's a better way I'm all ears since I'm trying to understand this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The thing with Express projects is that there is no "the one and only" standard for setting up a project structure. You can organize it in any way, as long as it makes sense and is understandable. In your case, it's totally fine to have controllers in the `controllers/` directory for a couple of reasons:

1. It makes sense to separate the logic into separate files
2. It's clear what the directory is for just by reading its name
3. The files from `controllers/` dir can be easily imported into `routes/` files

So I would say it's OK, you can go with that. But at the same time, feel free to reorganize that if you'll feel that you are getting lost in your project - you won't break any rules because there aren't any.